# Does newton's method work for non-roots?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

So if you have $f(x)$ and the associated tangent line $y=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0)$, then standard newton's method is $x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$ because you are looking for points $(x_{root}, 0)$.

But what if you are looking for any $y$ in the range of $f$?

Can we simply use the tangent line and set $y=c$ to get $x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{c - f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$?

Does it hold up in the multi-variable case $\vec{x_{n+1}}=\vec{x_n} + [Df(\vec{x_n)}]^{-1}(\vec{c}-f{\vec{x_n}})$

Comment: What do you mean by "any $(x,y)$"? Presumably, you mean an $(x,y)$ that lies on the graph. And presumably we have already decided what $y$ should be (if we have decided what $x$ should be, we can just calculate the value of the function).

Comment: Right any x,y that lies on the graph. Well we have a target y, but we don't know which x gives us that y (as in the root finding case), so we use newton's method to find it instead of solving for it. Edited my question for more clarity.

Comment: If you are looking for some $x$ such that $f(x)=y$ where the target $y$ is specified, then apply any root-finding method to $g(x)=f(x)-y$.

Comment: Hey nice way to think about it. But why do we give precedence to roots? Why is root finding not a more specific method to finding any y?

Comment: @user947659 Because 1) They are actually more important, and 2) as the above comment says, it is easy to adjust the method to find any value.

Answer (score 1):

So we must iterate

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \dfrac{f(x_n)-c}{f'(x_n) }$$